# Kissing tzitzit for maariv

Tags: tzitzis, maariv, shema, kissing

Why don't we kiss the tzitzit during the Vayomer section of shma of maariv? I would think we would since we are reading the same text as we do for shacharit.

Comment: Why kiss the tztzit at all at any time during the day? There is no explicit mitzvah to kiss them - only to wear them.

Comment: @DanF Because Shulchan Aruch writes that for חיבוב מצוה one should kiss the tzitzis when mentioning them in Shema.

Comment: Probably because we can't 'see' them at night. Electrical lighting does not change the reality of nighttime darkness ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no Miswa of Sisit at night (see Rabenu Behaye to Numbers 15:38-39).

Comment: Thank you. btw- i have never seen those spellings for מצוה and ציצית. Do you know where they come from?

Comment: @AriA 100+ years ago ALL Sefaradim would pronounce the words that way. The way you see most Sefaradim speaking nowadays has many reforms from Ashkenazim.

Comment: This doesn't answer for the Rosh who holds there is a mitzva of tzitzit at night for beged yom.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a separate question.

Comment: Why? The question asked according to everyone. You answered half way (and the easier half to answer mind you).

Comment: Are you implying that tzitzit is not a cheftza shel mitzva at night? So you can throw it out at night? As long as it still a cheftza shel mitzva, you would have to treat it with kavod, so kissing it upon mentioning it is not unreasonable at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA it's not a bad idea, but since there is no Miswa it's not kedai for the Posekim to mention a custom like this.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the Mishnah in brachos (I think it's the end of the first perek) the only reason we say vayomer at night is because it references yitzias mitzrayim. In theory, we don't really care about the tzitzis mention.

Comment: Does it say that we do care about the tzitzit part in the morning? Or is it always just because of Yetziat Mitzrayim, because in that case you still haven't shown a distinction.

Comment: Obviously we care about tzitzis during shacharis we kiss them!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_logic