# Does one need to fulfill the 248 words when reciting Shema outside the timeframe of Kri'at Shema?

Tags: minhag, chazzan-prayer-leader, shema, minyan

[O.C. 61:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=184) states that one should recite a total of 248 words when saying *Kri'at Shema*. As there are only 245 words, the last 3 words are fulfilled by listening to the Shat'z repeat the ה אלקיכם אמת. Rama"h in  says that there is a minhag that a *yachid* (individual) should say the 3 words אל מלך נאמן as a substitute.

I am unsure if this requirement is directly attached to the mitzvah of reciting Kri'at Shema, meaning during its timeframe. If I understand correctly, one who recites Shema before or after that period fulfills the mitzva of Torah learning, but not of reciting Shema.

So, does one who prays individually need to recite אל מלך נאמן. And, perhaps, more practically, many shuls say Shema after the time on Shabbat and Yom Tov mornings and before the time on summer Friday nights. Does the chazzan need to repeat ה אלקיכם אמת or does this accomplish nothing?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55719/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting info, there. Prob. warrants a bounty.

Comment: I believe the Chabad custom is for even an individual to recite "Hashem Elokeichem Emes" at the end instead of saying "Keil Melech Ne'eman" before Kriyas Shema, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ezra I did notice something like that on the Chaba"d site, I believe. The thinking is that "El Melech Ne'eman" is a hefsek. BTW, not that it's your fault, but, it's too bad that you never met Rav Schneerson, personally. Much of the recorded Chaba"d tunes that you hear on the tanks and in many places were arranged by my father in law, a"h. He played clarinet. So, he frequently met with the rebbe, mostly on music-arrangement matters.

Comment: @DanF It is ashame. Unfortunately he passed away 6 years before I was born, so I couldn't really help it. That's simply amazing about your father-in-law!

Comment: Yes its the Chabad minhag to not say the "Keil Melech Ne'eman" but rather to have the individual repeat "Hashem Elokeichem Emes"

Comment: My simple answer is that you should have the 248 words at all times since the intent is to match each word with one of the limbs/organs of your body. Who cares if it is "on time"? It still shouldn't be skipped.

Comment: For those who follow the inner teachings of the Torah in regard to this, it is important to recite all 248 words even if past the time for Kriat Shema. The relation to the limbs of the male body, mentioned by David Kenner, is correct. But the limbs of the male body are also associated to each of the 248 positive mitzvot. It relates to accepting the 'Yoke of the Mitzvot' which is part of the recital of Shema. To leave out those 3 extra words implies you do not accept all the positive commandments.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I'd like to see you expand on this topic. The mitvah of reciting Shema on "pshat" interpretation does not seem to require specifically 248 words. I assume that reciting Shema is *D'Oraita*. The Torah does not mention *El Melech Ne'man*, the word *Emet* or the concept that *betzibur* the Shat"z repeats the last 3 words.