# Quality of Sh'ma repeated in its proper time

Tags: tefilla, time, shema, loud-quiet

Often, I find myself at a ma'ariv minyan that meets before "nightfall" and someone invariably makes the announcement that we should all remember to [repeat](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Repeating_Shema_at_Night) the sh'ma after tzeit hakochavim. I also know that to be yotzei saying the sh'ma properly one should [say](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15488/1362) the words [audibly](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-shema) and clearly, even louder than one says the [amida](https://www.aish.com/atr/Praying-Audibly.html).

But if I know I am davening at a time when my saying the sh'ma is not efficacious towards fulfilling my obligation, must I still say the words out loud? Can I say them at the lowered level of the amida so that they are still "prayer" but not as loud as the sh'ma should be?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87110/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55719/759

Comment: There are rishonim who believe shema before nightfall does fulfill your obligation, and it’s possible that you may forget to repeat it, so it’s probably worth saying the first shema as properly as possible